# Mysterious Segment Fault

Tags: c#, c++, mono, c++17, game-engine

I having a very peculiar problem with my library. The simple example below ***works perfectly***.  But the more complex use case ***doesn't***. The setStaticField function call gives a segfault. I’ll show where in the function later.

This is the working example

```cpp
int main()
{
    Hunter::VM vm;
    Hunter::Script* s = vm.createScript("test.dll");
    Hunter::Class c = s->getClass("", "Entity");
    c.setStaticField("test", vm.newString("YO!!!"));

    return 0;
}
```

The short version of my library is this: its for embedding C# with the mono framework, though I’m pretty sure my issue isn’t related to the mono API. You first create a VM, which I basically a wrapper for a MonoDomain. Then you create scripts out of that VM. Scripts are essentially wrappers around a MonoAssembly  and its matching MonoImage. Then you get a Class object from a script, which is a wrapper around a MonoClass. setStaticField does what you’d expect, it sets a static member variable of a C# class to the value provided. Again, the example above functions fully. But the one below does not.

game.h

```cpp
// includes and other inline variable declarations
inline Hunter::VM csharpVM;
```

```cpp
// other includes

#include "../game.h"

// other functions

void loadScript(Scene* const a_scene, Json::Value a_data, entt::entity a_e)
{
    std::string scriptPath = a_scene->path + a_data.asString();

    scriptPath.erase(scriptPath.size() - 2, 2);
    scriptPath += "dll";
    Hunter::Script* s = csharpVM.createScript(scriptPath.c_str());
    a_scene->registry.emplace<Hunter::Script*>(a_e, s);

    Hunter::Class c = s->getClass("", "Part");
    std::cout << "About to push: " << &a_e << std::endl;
    c.setStaticField("partID", static_cast<void*>(&a_e));
    int sceneInt = reinterpret_cast<int>(a_scene);
    c.setStaticField("scenePtr", &sceneInt);
    std::cout << "Scene pointer: " << a_scene << "\nScene int: " << sceneInt << "\nScene Pointer back: " << reinterpret_cast<Scene*>(sceneInt) << std::endl;

    s->getStaticMethod("Part:onCreate()")();
}
```

This function is supposed to load in a script using my Hunter library, attach to an Entt entity (the ECS I use. Not importation here.), set it’s partID field to its ID within Entt, set it’s scenePtr member to a pointer to the scene that it is a part of, and then call its onCreate method. The method call ***works***.  But both of the setStaticField calls give segfaults on the last line of the function (the actual call to set the value)

```cpp
void setStaticField(const char* const a_name, void* a_value)
{
     MonoClassField* const field = mono_class_get_field_from_name(this->m_class, a_name);
     if (!field)
    {
        std::cerr << "Field error! Name: " << a_name << std::endl;
    }
    MonoVTable* const vtable = mono_class_vtable(mono_get_root_domain(), this->m_class);
    if (!vtable)
    {
        std::cerr << "VTable error! Name: " << a_name << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "About to send: " << a_value << std::endl;
    mono_field_static_set_value(vtable, field, a_value);
}
```

Lastly, here are the two C# scripts in use here. The appear to link together and inherit properly.

```
using System;

class Part : Game.PartBasic
{
    public static void onCreate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ScenePtr: ");
        Console.WriteLine(scenePtr);

        setPosition(500, 500);
    }

    public static void onUpdate()
    {

    }

    public static void onDestroy()
    {

    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Game
{
    public class PartBasic
    {
        public static uint partID;
        public static int scenePtr;

        public static void setPosition(int a_x, int a_y, int a_partID = -1)
        {
            if (a_partID == -1)
            {
                GameInternals.setPosition(a_x, a_y, partID, scenePtr);
            }else{
                GameInternals.setPosition(a_x, a_y, Convert.ToUInt32(a_partID), scenePtr);
            }
        }
    }

    class GameInternals
    {
        [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        public extern static void setPosition(int a_x, int a_y, uint a_partID, int scenePtr);
    }
}
```

Again, this all works in the top example but not here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have not already, use a debugger to locate the crash site and gather information. Add the information gathered to the question

Comment: A note about the title: I'm willing to bet that if the segfault wasn't mysterious you wouldn't be asking about it. You should make the title less generic and more informative. This will help future askers find the question and help attract the eye of potential answers.

Comment: @user4581301 The segmentation fault comes from the mono_field_static_set_value call at the end of Hunter::Class::setStaticField. I can't say where in the function, though, since my debugger can't step into it from some reason. Maybe because it's coming from a static link (I think?) library?

Comment: Short variable names like `s` should preferably only be used in extremely tiny scopes.

Does `Hunter::Script* s = csharpVM.createScript(scriptPath.c_str())` return a pointer to an already existing `Hunter::Script` or does it create one like the name suggests? It looks like it's leaking it in that case.

Comment: @user4581301 What kind of title would you recommend? Sorry, I'm new here. Just joined today.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It creates a new Script object. And thanks for pointing that out, you're right. It is leaking.

Comment: In that case I suggest `std::unique_ptr<Hunter::Script>` (if pointers are needed at all).

Comment: @TedLyngmo The only reason I'm using pointers is I'm not sure what kind of lifespan I need and what kind of cleanup is necessary for mono API related stuff. So I'm using pointers for now until I figure out if it's really needed.